# Convert string to int C# and place to the array

Tags: c#

I have one problem with convert word to int. Is it badly written?

```
foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                
                {
                    tab[i] = Int32.Parse(word);
                    Console.WriteLine(tab[i]);
                    i++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

On these line:

```
tab[i] = Int32.Parse(word);
```

I have error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

file:

> 0
>
> 12 0
>
> 19 15 0
>
> 31 37 50 0
>
> 22 21 36 20 0
>
> 17 28 35 21 25 0

Comment: What is the `word` you are trying to convert? How does your `line` look like?

Comment: word is a single word

Comment: When posting a question, please include all relevant input and desired outputs. (And in this case, the input is very important).

Comment: I read lines from txt file. with numbers

Comment: Please show us sample line :)

Comment: That means the string you are parsing doesn't look like an int.  Most non-numeric characters will cause this, like `$25`.

Comment: @KoraKora Is it possible you have multiple spaces between numbers, e.g. `0␣␣␣5`, or spaces before or after the list of numbers, e.g. `␣0␣5␣`? In this case `line.Split` would produce some empty strings. Use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid this.

Comment: I edit my question and add" wiev" of my file (of course it's withoutblank lines

Comment: @p.s.w.g where I should to place it?

Comment: `line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. There are several more examples in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there's something wrong with your input.  Consider using Int.TryParse, which will work assuming you're only looking to use well-formed integers.  You could also rig up some output on failure to give you an idea of what values are failing to parse, for example,

```
bool b;
int tempNumber;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        b = Int32.TryParse(word, out tempNumber);
        if (b) // success
        {
            tab[i] = tempNumber;
            Console.WriteLine(tab[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else // handle error
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Error: '" + word + "' could not be parsed as an Int32");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string doesn't represent a clean int. Probably a number with decimal places? (eg 5.5?) To catch and print the word you can just use a try/catch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But make sure what was the OP i/p and what is the expected o/p